# Flash CS6 not displaying AS3 projects (OS X)

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-cs6

Flash CS6 won't display any AS3 projects while debugging anymore. When compiling for debugging it turns up white in the default "debug window" inside of Flash. If I right-click in the debugger window it says "Movie not loaded". No compiler errors are shown. The resulting swf file only runs if opened with the Flash Player from Finder.

This applies for all projects that I know have been working fine up until now. I've also tested to create a new, blank FLA on which I only draw a rectangle with the same result.

If, however, I select a Flash Player version prior to 10 (falling back to AS2) as the target for the test file containing only a rectangle, it ***does*** compile and show up fine.

I've uninstalled Flash and Flash Builder (and deleting any trace of the applications in the Library folders) and then reinstalled it multiple times without any result. I've also tried to uninstall Flash Player and Flash Player Debugger to no avail. For this I'm following the advice on Adobe's site and are using their Flash Player uninstaller applications, but it doesn't seem to uninstall all instances of the Players...

I believe the problem lies in the version of *Flash Player Debugger* that Flash uses internally to display the swf when debugging and it seems to somehow persist between re-installations. Is there a sure-shot way to reset this entirely?

Has anybody encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem myself. It seems like the Chrome extension called FlashFirebug randomly causes these issues. When I deactivated the extension Flash started working properly again.